# Too many positional arguments! OneSignal, Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, onesignal

I am making an app using Flutter, Dart and Firebase. Now I am doing some research on how to implement `push-notifications` and I have been recommended to use OneSignal's SDK for flutter.

When trying to Initialise the notification I am getting a positional argument error, but the methods have been defined correctly with the exact number of parameters.

```
OneSignal.shared.init("App ID", {
  OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
  OSiOSSettings.inAppLaunchUrl: true
});
  OneSignal.shared.setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.notification);
```

This is the corresponding Init method:

```
  Future<void> init(String appId,
  {Map<OSiOSSettings, dynamic> iOSSettings}) async {
  _onesignalLog(OSLogLevel.verbose,
    "Initializing the OneSignal Flutter SDK ($sdkVersion)");

  var finalSettings = _processSettings(iOSSettings);

  await _channel.invokeMethod(
    'OneSignal#init', {'appId': appId, 'settings': finalSettings});
}
```

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That method has a named parameter:

```
 Future<void> init(String appId,
  {Map<OSiOSSettings, dynamic> iOSSettings})
```

You forgot the name (iOSSettings)

Change this:

```
OneSignal.shared.init("App ID", {
  OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
  OSiOSSettings.inAppLaunchUrl: true
});
```

To this :

```
OneSignal.shared.init("App ID", iOSSettings: {
  OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
 OSiOSSettings.inAppLaunchUrl: true
});
```

You can read more about that : https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#optional-parameters